# Como comparar, remover iguais, etc elementos de dois vetores em java?

Tags: java, lista, array

Estou fazendo um trabalho em java para realizar operações em conjunto, porém como estou aprendendo agora não sei como comparar os elementos dos vetores para fazer as seguintes operações, união, intersecção, diferença e complementar, quero fazer as operações depois de imprimir o segundo conjunto,  alguém poderia me ajudar como posso fazer isso nesse código. Segue o código de como está:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insira seis números para o primeiro conjunto.");
    int[] var1 = new int[6];
        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro número: ");
        var1[0]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o segundo número: ");
        var1[1]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o terceiro número: ");
        var1[2]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o quarto número: ");
        var1[3]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o quinto número: ");
        var1[4]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o sexto número: ");
        var1[5]= scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Insira mais seis números para o segundo conjunto.");
    int[] var2 = new int[6];
        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro número: ");
        var2[0]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o segundo número: ");
        var2[1]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o terceiro número: ");
        var2[2]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o quarto número: ");
        var2[3]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o quinto número: ");
        var2[4]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o sexto número: ");
        var2[5]= scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("O primeiro conjunto é: ");
    for(int i=0; i<var1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(var1[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("O segundo conjunto é: ");
    for(int a=0; a<var2.length; a++) {
        System.out.print(var2[a]+", ");
    }        
}
```

}

Comment: Precisa ser com array ou pode ser lista? Com lista fica muito mais fácil

Comment: Pode ser de qualquer jeito kkk, é que eu tava aprendendo com array, mas pode ser com lista, ainda não sei muito bem a diferença entre as duas

Answer (score 0):

Olá, veja se isso ajuda você. É um código simples, do jeito que você colocou. 
Eu apenas fiz um laço para ler as entradas (menos linhas de código) e, após imprimir os dois vetores, fiz as operações básicas (unir, elementos em comum, somar e subtrair). Há formas melhores de fazer isso, mas, pelo que entendi, você está iniciando agora, certo? Acho que fica legal focar no seu problema, entender a manipulação dos dados de um vetor para, posteriormente, seguir para implementações mais complexas usando os recursos do Java.

Boa sorte. =)

```
// Sendo bem pratico e simples.
import java.util.Scanner;

class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insira seis números para o primeiro conjunto.");
        int[] var1 = new int[6];
        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
            var1[i]= scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Insira mais seis números para o segundo conjunto.");
        int[] var2 = new int[6];
        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
            var2[i]= scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("O primeiro conjunto é: ");
        for(int i=0; i<var1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(var1[i]+", ");
        }

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("O segundo conjunto é: ");
        for(int a=0; a<var2.length; a++) {
            System.out.print(var2[a]+", ");
        }

        System.out.println("\nUniao:");
        // Uniao dos dois
        int[] uniao = new int[12];
        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ ) 
            uniao[i] = var1[i];

        for ( int i=6; i<12; i++ ) 
            uniao[i] = var2[i-6];

        for ( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
            System.out.print(uniao[i] + ", ");

        System.out.println("\nInterseccao:");
        // Interseccao dos dois
        int [] interseccao = new int[6];
        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
            for ( int j=0; j<6; j++ ) {
                if ( var1[i] == var2[j] ) {
                    interseccao[i] = var1[i];
                }
            }
        }

        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ )
            System.out.print(interseccao[i] + ", ");

        System.out.println("\nSoma:");
        // Soma dos dois ( x(a,b) + y(c,d) = z(a+c,b+d) )
        int [] soma = new int[6];
        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
            for ( int j=0; j<6; j++ ) {
                    soma[i] = var1[i] + var2[i];
            }
        }

        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ )
            System.out.print(soma[i] + ", ");

        System.out.println("\nSubtracao:");
        // Diferenca dos dois ( x(a,b) - y(c,d) = z(a-c,b-d) )
        int [] subtracao = new int[6];
        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
            for ( int j=0; j<6; j++ ) {
                    subtracao[i] = var1[i] - var2[i];
            }
        }

        for ( int i=0; i<6; i++ )
            System.out.print(subtracao[i] + ", ");

        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, agora vou estudar e por a mão na massa

Comment: De nada, Elber. Qualquer coisa, mande mais perguntas ou incremente esta. ;-)

Comment: A sua união gerou uma _bag_, não necessariamente um conjunto. Normalmente, se espera que a cardinalidade da união seja `|A| + |B| - |A^B|`, porém o seu conjunto resultante tem cardinalidade `|A| + |B|`. Você pode ver passando os conjuntos `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` e `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`, conjunto resultado esperado é `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`